# Edit a Node in excel TreeView VBA

Tags: vba, treeview

I'm writing a treeview for a userform in excel. I want to allow the user of the form to be able to edit any node's name and understand that the labeledit property is required, however I am unsure of the way to write the code. Any form of help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an ActiveX control from Microsoft dating back to the era of Visual Basic 6.0 (VBA is a variant of VB6)

Try this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172635(v=vs.90).aspx

One places the control on a form by going to the control toolbox and then selecting additional controls then from the list `Microsoft TreeView Control, version 6.0`

Using the Object Browser and selecting the `TreeView` class allows an investigation as to the methods and events that you need to use.  One must either set the `LabelEdit` property to `tvwAutomatic` and allow the system to handle the edit and one captures the event using `AfterLabelEdit` or one sets `LabelEdit` property to `tvwManual` and if the users double clicks on the node then you trap this is the `DoubleClick` event and manually call `StartLabelEdit`, use `AfterLabelEdit` to validate edit.

Some links:

[LabelEdit Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239004(v=vs.60).aspx%20LabelEdit)

[VB Coding Tip Treeview - Label-Editing](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/1545341/VB-Coding-Tip-Treeview---Label-Editing.htm)

Some sample code

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub TreeView1_DblClick()
    Dim nodSelected As MSComctlLib.Node
    Set nodSelected = TreeView1.SelectedItem
    If nodSelected.Text <> "root" Then
        TreeView1.StartLabelEdit
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    TreeView1.Style = tvwTreelinesPlusMinusText
    TreeView1.LabelEdit = tvwManual

    'Add some nodes to the TreeView
    Dim nodRoot As MSComctlLib.Node
    Set nodRoot = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Key:="root", Text:="root")

    '
    Dim nodChildren(1 To 2) As MSComctlLib.Node
    Set nodChildren(1) = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nodRoot, tvwChild, "child 1", "child 1")
    Set nodChildren(2) = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nodRoot, tvwChild, "child 2", "child 2")

    Dim nodGrandChildren(1 To 3) As MSComctlLib.Node
    Set nodGrandChildren(1) = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nodChildren(1), tvwChild, "grandchild 1", "grandchild 1")
    Set nodGrandChildren(2) = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nodChildren(2), tvwChild, "grandchild 2", "grandchild 2")
    Set nodGrandChildren(3) = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nodChildren(2), tvwChild, "grandchild 3", "grandchild 3")

End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_AfterLabelEdit(Cancel As Integer, NewString As String)
    ' Make sure that we have a value in the Label
    If Len(NewString) < 1 Then
        ' The Label is empty
        MsgBox "Error! You must enter a value"
        Cancel = True
    Else
        MsgBox "You successfully edited label to " & NewString
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: click on the root to expand the child nodes (not obvious).

Comment: Do you add the TreeView control to the userform yet as described in paragraph 4?

Comment: Go to your userform.  Then from the top menu go View->Toolbox.  Then in the new window in a grey blank area right click and select from pop-up menu additional controls then in list find and click "Microsoft TreeView Control, version 6.0" and click ok.  Then a new treeview icon will have appeared, click and hold then drag this to your form.  The default name for control will be Treeview1.

Comment: If you already have a Treeview then I guess you adapt the code.  I am puzzled as to the Text compile error.  In your Tools->References do you have `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)` checked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131817/discussion-between-s-meaden-and-martini).